# How to animate ImageAlpha of ImageView

Tags: android, animation, imageview, alpha

Since API16 ImageView.setImageAlpha(int) should be used instead of View.setAlpha(float) for better performance.

But how can I animate that value? I tried ValueAnimator without success.

`ObjectAnimator.ofInt(imageView, "imageAlpha", 0).start();`

I mean what Chet Haase is talking about here http://youtu.be/vQZFaec9NpA?t=33m

Comment: `view.animate().alpha()`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira: `view.animate().alpha()` is specifically unwanted here, since runs into the same performance hits that are talked about in the linked video. setImageAlpha takes a different path that avoids those performance hits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be fine. Maybe you forgot to specify the animation duration, or your alpha values are wrong (negative, too small, too close to notice)?

You can always animate using custom listener. It's longer, but easier to debug:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,255);
animator.setDuration(300);
animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        imageView.setImageAlpha(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
animator.start();
```